# Replacing an array element with elements of another array in state

Tags: reactjs

```
const [obj, setObj] = useState({a:[1, "x", 4]});
const arr = [2, 3];
```

After I fire the setObj function, I want whatever's in the second index of the "a" array that is "x" to be replaced with whatever's inside the arr, so the output should be:

```
{a:[1, 2, 3, 4]}
```

Also the contents of the arr are not predetermined and can change before the function is fired.

I tried copying the obj and modifying the array using the splice method, but it didn't work because the setObj function is bound to an onChange event and is fired repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the spread opeartor `...` to destructure `obj.a`. The below code replaces x with the contents of `arr`. Check this link for details on how spread operator works: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-spread-operator/

```
const [obj, setObj] = useState({a:[1, "x", 4]});
const arr = [2, 3];
const [one,two,...rest]=obj.a;
setObj({a:[one,...arr,...rest]});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const preState = {
  a: [1, "x", 4]
}
const arr = [2, 3];

const nextState = {
  a: preState.a.flatMap(v => v === 'x' ? arr : v)
}

console.log('nextState: ', nextState)
```